# C# change default order of execution partial classes in run time

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC with a database-first approach. Every table maps to a partial class in code. I want to add some properties to tables as a new partial class.

EF partial class is like this:

```
public partial class Test
{
    public int MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

(this class generates automatically).

I want to append other class to this with other partial class:

```
public partial class Test
{
    public int MyProp2
    {
        get
        {
            return MyProp;
        }
        set
        {
            MyProp = value;
        }
    }
}
```

but I don't know is compiler append second class to bottom on first one or in the top of that.

If the compiler appends it to bottom of first class, then both `MyProp` and `MyProp2` will be the value in the `MyProp2` and if it appends from top, both will be the value of `MyProp`.

How can I tell the compiler to append it from bottom?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.... But the order of partial classes is irrelevant. In the "total" class there will be both `MyProp` and `MyProp2`, and `MyProp2` will proxy `MyProp`

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, but it doesn't matter - the order in which source code is presented is of no consequence at all at the level you're concerned over..

These two classes are identical when compiled:

```
class Test
{
    public int MyProp { get; set; }
    public int MyProp2 { get => MyProp; set; }
}

class Test
{
    public int MyProp2 { get => MyProp; set; }
    public int MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

and it doesn't matter that one prop references the other.

Partial classes are combined into a single class, in any order (it doesn't matter, because the order of class level elements doesn't matter) during compilation

I understand why you might have assumed it does because local variables must be declared before they are used:

```
void Main(){
    Console.WriteLine(x); //doesn't work; can't use X before it's declared 
    int x = 1;
}
```

but this is not true of class properties, methods etc

Comment: the classes you wrote are identical but in the class i wrote the value of `MyProp` and `MyProp` are sensitive to order of the two partial classes and it is important which class is first in source code

Comment: *sensitive to order of the two partial classes* - no, they really aren't

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answer, the order of properties does not matter in a class.  A 'partial' class is not a different entity.  It is just a way of building a single class in two different files in your project.

> If the compiler appends it to bottom of first class, then both MyProp
> and MyProp2 will be the value in the MyProp2 and if it appends from
> top, both will be the value of MyProp.

No.  In your code both MyProp and MyProp2 are mapped to MyProp.  MyProp2 does not have its own backing field to store a value.  It uses MyProp ... always ... regardless of order.